# npm syscall symlink error -95 when installing node-sass on Docker for Windows

Tags: node.js, docker, hyper-v

In my application I have a dependency

```
"sass-loader": "^3.1.1"
```

I first ran a npm install directly from Windows, but when I tried to run the application it didn't work because the node version is different or something. So it told me to run:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

I tried to run it from within the container, but then I got an error

```
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! errno -95
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! nospc ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, symlink '../node-sass/bin/node-sass' -> '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/node-sass'
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to get around this error and install node-sass?

Currently using:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Docker 1.11.1-beta10 (build: 2446)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Run the command again with the parameter [`-no-bin-links`](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9901#issuecomment-146585579)

```
npm rebuild node-sass -no-bin-links
```

[`bin-links` from NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#bin-links):

> Set to false to have it not do this. This can be used to work around the fact that some file systems don't support symlinks, even on ostensibly Unix systems.

Comment: You can also apparently do `npm install -no-bin-links` if there's more than one package causing problems.

Comment: Should I do: ` npm rebuild node-sass -no-bin-links && npm install` ?

Comment: I seem to be getting this error running `npm install` from a symlinked folder, in which case this doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config set bin-links false
```

This command disables the creation of symbolic links during npm package installation.